# MySQL query doesn't find result when searching a String

Tags: php, mysql, string

I am having a Problem with a MySQL Query. My Database Structure looks like this:

```
id (PRIMARY_KEY, AUTO_INCREMENT)

deviceID (TEXT)

name (TEXT)

latidude (TEXT)

longitude (TEXT)
```

Now this is how the first Entry looks like (in the order like above):

```
1 fc29daf8-bc53-4235-a1df-7d54b4e67b4c username 46.993393 5.448076
```

I'm search the Database with this Query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM position WHERE deviceID = '$deviceID'");
```

But it doesn't find the entry. The deviceID is obtained from $_GET and it is exactly the same as this in the database. I also checked if it is right by printing it with echo.

It is sent to the PHP file like this:

```
read_uniqueid.php?deviceID=fc29daf8-bc53-4235-a1df-7d54b4e67b4c
```

and read from the .php file like this:

```
$deviceID = $_GET['deviceID'];
echo $deviceID.'<br>';
```

After those lines the query from above is sent.

There is a working connection to the database.I only have a Problem in the query if I search the name like that it works then I get all the other Entries.

This query works and gives me all entries:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM position WHERE name = '$name'");
```

Comment: what do you get when you doing this? : **$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM position WHERE deviceID = 'fc29daf8-bc53-4235-a1df-7d54b4e67b4c'");**

Try to run this "**SELECT name FROM position WHERE deviceID = 'fc29daf8-bc53-4235-a1df-7d54b4e67b4c'**" in Mysql DB and see if you get anything...

Comment: Please have a look into database security, Passing user params right into the DB is not a smart thing to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like,

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM position WHERE deviceID like '%$deviceID%'");
```

the column deviceID may have space in before or after the value.

Comment: @user1770465 fix the spaces instead. safer long term strategy

Comment: `trim($deviceID)` on `insert`